# Mibian options doesn't seem to work for different volatility values Python

Tags: python, package, finance, yahoo-finance, mibian

I'm working with a Python module call Mibian that calculates call and put options.
The parameters for Mibians Black-Scholes formula is as follows:

```
     import mibian as mb
     c =    mb.BS([Underlying Price, Strike Price interest rate, days to expiration],
            volatility).callPrice
```

Say I calculate a call option for AAPL (Apple.inc) stock with an underlying price of 143.14, strike price of 100, interest rate of 1%, expiration 17 days, and volatility is 19.42.

```
     call =  mb.BS([143.14, 100, 1, 17], 19.42).callPrice
     call

     43.186564497836812
```

The Ask value for AAPL is 43.50. So the two values are very close.
However, if I change the volatility to any value, unless it's extremely large, like, say 120, will it change at all. Call and put options with the Black-Scholes formula should be very sensitive to changes in volatility, but with Mibian, it hardly changes.
It's sensitive to changes in all parameters, except volatility.

```
     call = mb.BS([143.14, 100, 1, 17], 100).callPrice

     43.699404110772761

     #Volatility at 120.

     call = mb.BS([143.14, 100, 1, 17], 120).callPrice

     44.34924908915427
```

I want to be able to change only the volatility values later on in order to make a comparison between previous call and put values.
Am I missing something here, or does the Mibian equations not work properly? Hopefully I'm just being a dummy on this one. Any help on clarifying this issue? Many thanks.

Comment: from the source: `self.volatility = float(volatility) / 100` so looks like they divide the volatility you provide by 100 for whatever reason

Comment: Hey user, that's strange why they divide by 100. Not seen that before in any literature on options. I guess that explains why I can only see changes in the call price when I put in values above 120 :S Once I do a calculation though, say volatility = 120, call = 133. If I change volatiltiy = 1, the call still equals 133!

Answer (score 3):

If strike price ($100) is deep in the money by $43.14 (stock-strike)as in this case, volatility has little impact on option price. I changed the option price to $140, so the stock-strike is only $3.14, the volatility has great impact on call price.See below

```
call = mibian.BS([143.14, 140, 1, 17], 120).callPrice
```

> call
>   16.24

```
call = mibian.BS([143.14, 140, 1, 17], 20).callPrice
```

> call
>
> 4.36